# Translation: "break functionality" in german

Tags: translation

I'm currently writing a paper on test quality (concerning code development) and I've had problems trying to translate the following sentence (or rather, a more complex one, but this shorter version serves better to illustrate the problem).

> The tests ensure that your changes won't break existing functionality.

How would you translate the "break [...] functionality" part?
I've been thinking about:

> Funktionalität(en) / Features ...
>   ... kaputt machen (way too colloquial in my opinion)
>   ... stören (doesn't quite fit either)

Of course I could use negation and say

> Die Tests stellen sicher, dass bestehende Funktionalitäten auch weiterhin funktionieren.

However, I'm kind of ambitious to find a more direct translation. Any answers appreciated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Opposed to *to break* in English, *brechen* in German is of a pure **mechanical** quality (except in some rare corner cases like "eine Regel brechen"), so you cannot express "break functionality" with *brechen* in German.

You would normally express this with verbs like *beeinträchtigen* (which is clearly "negative") or *beeinflussen* (which just expresses a change).

So, your example sentence would probably end up somewhat like

> Die Tests stellen sicher, dass bestehende Funktionalitäten nicht beeinträchtigt werden.
>
> Die Tests stellen sicher, dass bestehende Funktionalitäten nicht beeinflusst werden.

I would definitively prefer the first one.

Comment: Warum aber umständliche *Funktionalitäten*? Würden es die einfacheren *Funktionen* nicht auch tun? - Ich hege den Verdacht, dass *Funktionalitäten* bloß aufgeblasene *Funktionen* sind; außer in dem einen Fall, wenn man von *Funktionalität* (im Singular) spricht und damit den Zustand meint, dass etwas funktioniert oder zweckmäßig eingerichtet ist.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann Dein Verdacht ist unbegründet: *Funktionen* sind im Programmierer-Jargon was ganz anderes als *Funktionalitäten* - Ein Programm **besteht** aus *Funktionen* (`int main(int argc, char *argv[])`) {}, stellt aber *Funktionalität* zur Verfügung.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann: Ich stimme tofro teilweise zu (direkt *in* der Programmierung hat *Funktion* eine recht feste Bedeutung), teilweise aber auch dir (der Hang, manchmal ein unnötig kompliziertes Wort zu verwenden, taucht sicherlich ab und an auf). Ich möchte aber auch noch eine weitere Sichtweise darlegen: Beschreibt man das Verhalten eines Programms, so bezieht sich *Funktion* meinem Gefühl nach auf einen konkreten, vom Benutzer aufrufbaren Befehl oder eine konkrete, vom Benutzer aktivierbare Option. Eine *Funktionalität* ist dagegen eher eine nutzbringende Verhaltensweise der ...

Comment: ... Anwendung, die bei der Ausführung mehrerer Befehle nebenbei zum Tragen kommen kann, die an sich aus mehreren zusammengehörigen Befehlen besteht (und somit nicht als konkreter Befehl vorliegt, sondern sich beispielsweise aus einer Befehlsfolge ergibt), oder die vielleicht auch nur einen Teil einer per Befehl erreichbaren Funktion darstellt.

Answer (score 1):

Da würde mir Folgendes einfallen:

> Die Tests stellen sicher, dass Ihre Änderungen bestehende
>   Funktionalitäten nicht beeinträchtigen.

Alternativen:

> - Die Tests stellen sicher, dass Ihre Änderungen bestehende Funktionalitäten unangetastet lassen.
> - Die Tests stellen sicher, dass Ihre Änderungen bestehende Funktionalitäten nicht berühren.
> - Die Tests stellen sicher, dass bestehende Funktionalitäten von Ihren Änderungen unberührt bleiben.